# Disable update to many to one entity in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a Parent and Child entity. Child has a Manytoone annotation to reference Parent. The use case is that when i load a child by `findById` and get the parent out using the `getter`. then If I update the parent, I am able to save the parent. I do not want the parent to be updatable which is pulled out from a child.

1. I want only to update parent if **I directly find it by id and change attribute and save.**
2. I know hibernate has no info when i do **getParent()** from child that it got it from child and not find by id and makes an update to parent.
3. I tried Immutable annotation on ManytoOne on Parent but it does not prevent an update to be fired.

Is there any way that I can make the parent pulled out from a child non-updatable?

feel free to ask any clarifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing, in fact belongs to the Hibernate `Session`. It has nothing with *Cascading*. Because the session is designed to be a `unit-of-work` for us.

Whenever you access an object 1) by ID or 2) by reference, this object is *(from that moment)* "cached" in the `Session`. It is one instance shared accross all the handling during the `Session` life-time.

So, once, the `Parent` is loaded into session, and you are amending it anyhow, and later `Session` is **flushed** - any changes to `Parent` are persisted.

You can call [session.evict(parent)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/Session.html#evict%28java.lang.Object%29) explicitly, to avoid changes propagation during the `Flush`.

*But It seems to me a bit weird, that you are changing the Parent (accidently...maybe) while working with child and not willing to store these changes. Other words, maybe solution is to change the approach.*

Comment: the idea is to not allow the child to allow update parent. i want child to have only read only parent entities. i did not want to manually evict or detach it

Comment: As I said, in this case, our problem is, that we have not-readonly entity (Parent) loaded in the session. Any changes to it, will cause the SQL UPDATE statement, whenever session.flush() is called. I have (in my experience) never faced the issue you are describing. Either I am persisting Parent and its children (both are changed) or I am working with a child, touching the Parent - but not changing it at all. So I would suggest to think about the overall design... if you know what I mean. Something seems to be incorrect

Comment: i am aware the the object is shared. it's just that i would like to update parent only if it is explicitly fetched, and not from a child object.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `EntityManager.detach()` on the parent that you obtain through the getter. Any change made to the detached entity will not be synchronized to the database.

Comment: i guess there is no automated solution which by default gives me read only entity.